# How to implement floating divs draggable in ckeditor for all browsers?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Currently if we add a floating div with position absolute in ckeditor, a draggable handle will appear in firefox.

`<div id="Layer1" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:115px; z-index:1; left: 46px; top: 90px;">Here is a floating layer</div>`

But the behaviour is not consistent across browsers. Is there a way to enable dragging option to selected divs with in ckeditor?

Is it possible to use the jquery draggable here? In that case how do we include the required jquery libraries to the ckeditor wysiwyg area and bind the event to the div?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a workaround for the above problem. In the ckeditor instnaceReady, I've added the js to head part of the ckeditor iframe.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
   var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;
   var h = oEditor.document.getHead();
   var element1 = oEditor.document.createElement( 'script' );
   element1.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js');
   element1.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
   h.append(element1);
   var element2 = oEditor.document.createElement( 'script' );
   element2.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js');
   element2.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
   var element3 = oEditor.document.createElement( 'script' );
   element3.setAttribute('src','drag.js');
   element3.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
   h.append(element2);
   h.append(element3);

   function drag() {
    try {
     $('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.EnableDrag();
    }
    catch(err) {
     setTimeout(drag,10);
    }
   };

  setTimeout(drag,10);
});
```

In the drag.js, I added the EnableDrag() function.

```
EnableDrag = function() {
  $('#Layer1').draggable();                
}
```

This code works on ff, chrome and IE.

There are still some issues with the code, every time, we change the content of ckeditor or use the source button, the binding and js included in the head got lost. Also the function EnableDrag is not available immediately after creating and appending the objects. So I used setTimeout to add a delay. In firefox, the dragging is not very smooth.

If anyone knows the correct way to implement this, please help.